# sharing video using uiactivityViewcontroller

Tags: swift3, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am developing an application and want to share images videos and other files saved into my document directory using uiactivityviewcontroller. images and files sharing is working properly. 
Code for image sharing

```
var textToShare : Any!
textToShare = UIImage(data:data)//data of an image
```

Code for other files which are stored into document directory.

```
var textToShare : Any!
textToShare = url//url of file saved into document directory
```

But i don't know how to share video. After this all i am using following code to use activityviewcontroller.

```
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [textToShare], applicationActivities: nil)
    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view // so that iPads won't crash

    // exclude some activity types from the list (optional)
    activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [ UIActivityType.airDrop, UIActivityType.postToFacebook ]

    // present the view controller
    self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First get video file path

```
 let videoURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:localVideoPath)
```

And then pass this path to `UIActivityViewController` like below

```
let activityItems = [videoURL, "Check this out!" ]
let activityController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: activityItems, applicationActivities: nil)

activityController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
activityController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = self.view.frame

self.presentViewController(activityController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

*Updated Code for Swift 4*

```
    let localVideoPath = "your_video_path_here..."
    let videoURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: localVideoPath)

    let activityItems: [Any] = [videoURL, "Check this out!"]
    let activityController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: activityItems, applicationActivities: nil)

    activityController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = view
    activityController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = view.frame

    self.present(activityController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: i already have video url but it is not stored in local path. it is saved into the gallery. i need to export it first. can you explain how to export video?? i already tried this but unable to to share video.

Comment: Yes, thats okay using path provided by gallery. Are you using UIImagePickerController?

Comment: no right now i am using phasset to get url of all videos stored into gallery. in future i am thinking to switch on UiImagePickerController but right now i do only have url of video and i want to export it. if there is no way to export it by using only url then let me know. i will make changes in my code to use UiImagePickerController. tahnk you :)

Comment: i have changed my code to uiImagePicker can you please tell me how to share it now.

Comment: your method works for uiimagepickercontroller thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

**To share video from Local Document directory path**

```
func shareVideo(videoPath : String){
        let localVideoPath = videoPath
        let videoURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: localVideoPath)

        let activityItems: [AnyObject] = [videoURL as AnyObject]
        let activityController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: activityItems, applicationActivities: nil)

        activityController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = view
        activityController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = view.frame

        self.present(activityController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 5.0 // Method with FileManager & file name

```
  let localVideoPath = "video_file_name.mp4" // NAME OF THE VIDEO FILE
                
    if let dir = try? FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false) {
                   
      let videoURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: dir.absoluteString).appendingPathComponent(localVideoPath)

      let activityItems: [Any] = [videoURL]
      let activityController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: activityItems, applicationActivities: nil)

      activityController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = view
      activityController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = view.frame
      self.present(activityController, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func shareUsingActivity() {

    let yourPath = ""
    let yourUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: yourPath)
    let activity: [Any] = [yourUrl, "Your custom message here…"]
    let actController = UIActivityViewController(activity: activity, applicationActivities: nil)
    actController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = view
    actController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = view.frame
    self.present(actController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```